# Why does compiz consume 100% CPU when the lock screen is active?

Tags: compiz

I have noticed that the CPU load is strangely high when the lock screen is active. Then I have found out that it is compiz generating this load. What I can hardly figure out myself is why is that and how to fix that...

Comment: You could collect more data (too much to post) with `top -b -n 30 -d 5.00 >/tmp/top.out`, then lock the sceen, wait 2 minutes, unlock,  and view `/tmp/top.out`. Read `man top`

Comment: I don't know why you deleted your old question, and my comment, and then made a new question. Again, yes similar happens for me. It is not related to screen blanking, but is related to screen lock. In my case compiz goes from 0% during screen blank to about 30 % of one CPU during screen lock. This might be related to this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1448535). Also see [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/attachment.php?attachmentid=261802&d=1430925869), but that graph is package power, not CPU usage.

Comment: Sorry for your comment, @DougSmythies, but the previous question has became irrelevant (IMHO) as far as we know that's compiz. Now we need to figure out what's wrong with compiz again (yes, I am not surprised, there is always something wrong with it according to my 8 years long  experience with it, that's a huge pity Unity needs it).